# psycopg2 "ALTER TABLE File_Data_details DROP COLUMN left" syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2, pgadmin-4

I was trying to **delete a column** named "left" from my POSTGRES table called "File_Data_details", using **psycopg2 python**

This is my query:

```
query="ALTER TABLE public.File_Data_details DROP COLUMN left"
```

I am getting the below error.

**
**SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "left" LINE 1: ALTER TABLE public.File_Data_details DROP COLUMN left**
**

I think 'left' is some keyword that is used for some operation in POSTGRES. But I have no idea how to delete this column from my table.

Some site suggested to use square brackets. I tried that way also.

```
query="ALTER TABLE public.File_Data_details DROP COLUMN [left]"
```

But didn't work.

Could someone help me solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square brackets are for MSSQL.  Use double quotes.

```
alter table public.File_Data_details drop column "left"
```

Comment: Yes. It worked. Thanks. Actually what I tried earlier were single quotes. That was the issue. With double quotes, it worked. Thank you :)